# correct pthread_mutex_lock type in a callback function

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I have a third party callback function invoked frequently from the global scope and in order to sync my buffer sequence I use a  pthread_mutex_lock with the type PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK

The desired behavior is that each call to the callback function is blocked until the processing is complete of prior one. Is the type of mutex I am currently using appropriate for this, as I am currently experiencing a weird system lockup with complete freeze of operations and suspect that the code after my handling of lock error is causing this. By design the lock should never fail.

Comment: It sounds like the mutex should be locked right at the beginning of the function, and released at the end. Is that so? Perhaps the same mutex is used in other parts of the program. Also, could you paste the code you use for locking as well as the error handling and unlocking parts of the code?

Comment: Well, a PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK enables you to check if the mutex got locked recursivly by a thread. Did it ? Did you check ? Are there code paths which fails to unlock the mutex ? What did you do ? You need to provide more information, and possibly show some code, otherwise it will be hard to even guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your description isn't very clear. Things don't normally get invoked from the "global scope", only certain kinds of constructors and destructors. Maybe what you're talking about is an external function call: the callback is called by some foreign context in another software component.  You also don't make it clear who is writing the callback. Is this a third-party library calling your registered callback? A "third party callback" would be a function in a third-party library, which is registering itself as a callback to you.

I'm going to assume that you're calling some third party library, which invokes your callback, and you're getting into a deadlock situation, either in your code or in the third party.

If the deadlock is occurring in the third party code, maybe you are not observing the proper rules for what the callback may or may not do. Are you making calls into that third party code out of the callback? Maybe you are not allowed to do that, or not certain ones. Maybe the third party library holds a mutex while invoking your callback, and a function you're calling from that callback tries to acquire the same mutex.

If the deadlock is in your own code, on your own mutex, maybe you're doing something silly, like holding the mutex, calling the third-party code and then trying to lock the mutex again.  If it's as simple as that, there are various approaches. One is never to hold a mutex when calling external components (which is often  good idea because mutexes should be held for short periods of time to avoid contention). Release a mutex on the way out of your code and re-acquire it on the way in.  Sometimes this is inconvenient, because whenever you release your mutex, the "world changes" and you have to re-examine the state of the protected variables and handle the cases that can occur. Bugs can creep in whereby your code relies on assumptions from the previous time it held the mutex which no longer apply because it released the mutex.

Another approach that can work with this callback situation is for the callback to assume 
that the mutex is already held and don't lock it twice. If the callback is some general function that is used as a non-callback also, split it into a non-locking version and a locking one. Bind the callback to the non-locking one.

Another thing that can cause deadlocks, is acquiring multiple locks in opposite order. This easily happens when threads traverse the object hiearchies of a big program in different orders. E.g. some thread works with Object A which invokes a method on object B, and another thread is doing something which goes from B to A.  The technique of always releasing a lock when you're leaving a module will help prevent this. In situations where you can't do that, you may be able to refactor the code so that it always acquires locks in the same order.

Another tool is different kinds of locks. Recursive locks can help (though they are a kludge). Read-write locks can help in some situations. "Lock-free" algorithms (which use tiny mutexes in the form of atomic machine instructions instead of big OS mutexes) also.

Comment: This is a series of guesses rather than an answer.

Comment: That is basically correct; but I don't see an obvious way to revise the "guesses", based on the information given so far. No concrete code, or a more detailed description of the scenario, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the done thing is to add a comment on the question asking for more information, and save the answers until they are possible..